# Digital persona SDK - native problems

Tags: android, multithreading, java-native-interface, jnienv, digital-persona-sdk

I am using in my app Digital Persona SDK for fingerprint identification.
When i use the identify function on less then 250 fmds it works fine.

```
Engine.Candidate candidates[] = m_engine.Identify(searchedFmd, 0, fmdArray, DEFAULT_THRESHOLD, 1); //fmdArray < 250
```

But with fmdArray > 250 it gives me a native runtime error:

```
A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
```

Now i runned this app on couple of android devices and came to conclusion that my app crushes with fmdArray > 250 when its running on android 7. But android 8 works fine. In 8 i can preform a check on even 4000 fmds and it works fine.

But i need to run this code in a specific device, that running android 7.

I tried to run it in couple of threads of 250 fmds only. But after single run there is another problem with the SDK. On the second run it doesnt works.

This is what i do:
First i get a fingerprint capture that i want to identify:

```
Reader.CaptureResult capture = m_reader.Capture(fidFormat, UrUSDK.DefaultImageProcessing, m_DPI, timeout);
// In second run, code after this line is not executed.
// My guees its not coming back from native. No exeptions. No errors.
...
Fmd scannedFmd = m_engine.CreateFmd(capture.image, fmdFormat);
...
int index = identifyFinger(fmds, scannedFmd);
...

    private int identifyFinger(List<Fmd> fmdSearchArray, Fmd scannedFmd) {
        List<List<Fmd>> lists = splitToChunks(fmdSearchArray);
        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(-1);
        List<Callable<Void>> threads = new ArrayList<>(lists.size());
        AtomicInteger iteratorIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            int currentChunk = i;
            Callable<Void> thread = () -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " with chunk: " + iteratorIndex.getAndIncrement());
                Fmd[] fmds = lists.get(currentChunk).toArray(new Fmd[IDENTIFY_BOUNDARY]);
                try {
                    Engine.Candidate[] candidates = m_engine.Identify(scannedFmd, 0, fmds, threshold, 1);
                    if (candidates.length > 0) {
                        index.set(candidates[0].fmd_index + (currentChunk * IDENTIFY_BOUNDARY));
                    }
                } catch (UareUException e) {

                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " with chunk: " + currentChunk + " finished!");
                return null;
            };
            threads.add(thread);
        }

        try {
            List<Future<Void>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(threads);
            System.out.println("All threads finished: " + index.get());
            return index.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

...

private List<List<Fmd>> splitToChunks(List<Fmd> fmdSearchArray) {
        int size = fmdSearchArray.size();
        List<List<Fmd>> lists;
        if (size > IDENTIFY_BOUNDARY) {
            int chunks = size / IDENTIFY_BOUNDARY;
            if (size % IDENTIFY_BOUNDARY > 0) {
                chunks++;
            }
            lists = new ArrayList<>(chunks);
            for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
                if (i + 1 == chunks) {
                    lists.add(new ArrayList<>(fmdSearchArray.subList(i * IDENTIFY_BOUNDARY, size)));
                    break;
                }
                lists.add(new ArrayList<>(fmdSearchArray.subList(i * IDENTIFY_BOUNDARY, (i + 1) * IDENTIFY_BOUNDARY)));
            }
        } else {
            lists = new ArrayList<>(1);
            lists.add(fmdSearchArray);
        }
        return lists;
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it runs once. But at another try it doesnt come back from the native code of Caprture call.

So my question is:
How i can overcome this and make it work from my java code? 
Or at least what is the direction of the solution?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show _how_ you use the API? It sounds like it is not releasing all of its local references.

Comment: Why do you do all requests in parallel instead of sequentially? Does the SDK promise thread safety?

Comment: Cause sequental execution will take too long for identify one fingerprint. For 4000 fmds its more than 3 seconds. The maximum we can allow is ~1.4

Comment: Suggest you discuss with the SDK provider to work out how to improve speed, then.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that this `Identify` function holds on to at least two references per returned `Candidate` after pushing it to the result array. It should instead release the references after pushing, so its use of the (limited) local reference table remain constant. You should file a bug about that.

The simplest workaround for now is to cut your `fmdArray` into 250-sized chunks and call `Identify` for each chunk.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to show that i tried it. And the problem i facing in this solution.